# Do Cauchy-Riemann Equations Hold?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f(z) = \frac{(\overline{z})^2}{z}$ if $z \neq 0$ and $f(z) = 0$ if $z = 0$

Do Cauchy-Riemann Equations only hold at (0,0)?

I'm confused as to how to start this problem. I have tried converting the function $\frac{(\overline{z})^2}{z}$ into the form U(x,y) + iV(x,y) by letting $z = x+yi$ and $\overline{z} = x-yi$ but that just makes things over complicated and I end up with division by zero at the point (0,0).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The function is $(\bar z)^3/\lvert z\rvert^2$, from which it is easy to extract the real and imaginary parts. Is that where you got stuck?

Comment: I've gotten this far, and even further as shown in the answer below, i substituted z=x+yi into $\frac{(\overline{z})^3}{|z|^2}$ and simplify that to a real and imaginary parts but I get stuck evaluating the CRE at (0,0)

Answer (score 1):

First, using the form $u+iv$ this problem can be solved after a lengthy calculation in which it is show that the function is differenciable in the real sense. You obtain that

$$f(x+iy)=\frac{x^3-3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{3x^2y-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

And here, differentiating, using the definition of derivative, we obtain at $(0,0)$ that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\frac{x^3-3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}-0}{x}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2-3y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

Where we see that this limit does not exist, since by taking the paths $t\mapsto(\sqrt{3}t,t)$ and $t\mapsto(t,t)$ we obtain different limits when $t\to 0$.

Second, you can do this directly by computing

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\left(\frac{\overline{z}}{z}\right)^2$$

And then use polar form to see that the limit does not exist, since it depends of the path of approximation to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy Riemann Equations are not well-defined. The function is continuous, but its derivative are not. Consider $\operatorname{f}(x+iy) = (x-iy)^2/(x+iy)$. Let $\operatorname{U}(x,y)$ be the real part and $\operatorname{V}(x,y)$ be the imaginary part of $\operatorname{f}(x+iy)$. We have:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\operatorname{f}(x+iy) &=& \frac{(x-iy)^2}{x+iy} \\ \\
&\equiv& \frac{(x-iy)^2(x-iy)}{(x+iy)(x-iy)} \\ \\
&\equiv& \left(\frac{x(x^2-3y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right) + i\left(\frac{y(3x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right) \end{array}

If we approach $z=0$ along different paths then we get different answers. For example, let $\gamma_{\theta}(r) = r\!\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}$, so that $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$. What happens as $r \to 0$? Well,

\begin{array}{ccc}
(\operatorname{U}_x\circ \, \gamma_{\theta})(r) &\equiv& 12\cos^2\theta -8\cos^4\theta-3 \\
(\operatorname{U}_y\circ \, \gamma_{\theta})(r) &\equiv& -8\sin\theta\cos^3\theta \\
(\operatorname{V}_x\circ \, \gamma_{\theta})(r) &\equiv& 8\sin^3\theta\cos\theta \\
(\operatorname{V}_y\circ \, \gamma_{\theta})(r) &\equiv& 8\cos^4\theta - 4\cos^2\theta-1\\
\end{array}

These expressions are independent of $r$, and so as $r \to 0$ we get partial derivatives which depend upon the angle of approach. Moreover, computing the actual Cauchy Riemann equations does not rid us of the problem:

\begin{array}{ccc}
((\operatorname{U}_x-\operatorname{V}_y) \circ \, \gamma_{\theta})(r) &\equiv& 16\cos^2\theta - 16\cos^2\theta -2 \\
((\operatorname{U}_y+\operatorname{V}_x) \circ \, \gamma_{\theta})(r) &\equiv& 4\sin(2\theta)(1-2\cos^2\theta)
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
In the polar coordinates $z=re^{i\theta},\;\;(r>0),$ 
$$f(re^{i\theta})=re^{-3i\theta}=r\cos{3\theta}-3i\sin{3\theta}.$$
Then substitute $f$ into the 
Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar coordinates
$$\begin{cases}{ \partial u \over \partial r } = {1 \over r}{ \partial v \over \partial \theta}, \\ { \partial v \over \partial r } = -{1 \over r}{ \partial u \over \partial \theta}. \end{cases}$$